# Python Determine if IP Address is a remote IP

Tags: python, networking, ip

I will be pulling a list of IP Addresses and **I want to determine which ones are a remote IP Address**. How can I accomplish this?

I am new to network programming so please excuse me if this is a stupid question. I would really like some direction toward  a solution to this problem. It would also help if python code was provided. Thanks!

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) has a section that explains how to figure what you ask.

Comment: @RonMaupin where does it talk about remote ip

Comment: It has a section that describes how to determine if addresses are on the same network. That is what hosts do to determine if the packet should be framed for the destination on the local network, or if it should be framed for the gateway. If you are programming for IPv4 addresses, you should learn and understand everything in both parts of the answer. Specifically, the **IPv4 Network Address** section describes how to determine the network address of a particular address.